# url not working in ahref, but does in plain text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am creating a spfx widget using react that consumes a JSON api end point. It then spits out the lastest few posts.

When adding the `{url}` variable into an `<a href=""></a>` - The url is a random localhost one instead of the full url

```
  <a href="{url}">{url}</a>
```

The `{url}` inside the a tag is the actual full link `https://etc..` but the one inside `href=""` turns into a localhost link like:
https://localhost:4321/temp/%7B%60url%60%7D

Any ideas why?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you want to run JavaScript for an attribute, use curly brackets but no quotation marks:

```js
<a href={url}>{url}</a>
```

Comment: Can't accept your answer for another 13 minutes! Worked perfectly thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of the double quotes surrounding the JSX variable.

```
<a href={url}>{url}</a>
```

Updating it like so would work

Answer (score 0):

The value inside the curly brackets is expected to be a JavaScript Expression i.e., a function, an object, a variable, or any code that will be calculated later. But passing the value within double quotes turns it into a simple string. So to solve this issue use

```
<a href={url}>{url}</a>
```